# angular.js http post to MVC async Task<ActionResult> web method fails

Tags: angularjs, model-view-controller, asynchronous, controller

I Am trying to call an Async method in MVC controller (example Login) from an angular client and calls fail. I tried it with google postman tool also.

```
    //
    // POST: /Account/Login
    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return View(model);
        }

        // This doesn't count login failures towards account lockout
        // To enable password failures to trigger account lockout, change to shouldLockout: true
        var result = await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Email, model.Password, model.RememberMe, shouldLockout: false);
        switch (result)
        {
            case SignInStatus.Success:
                return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
            case SignInStatus.LockedOut:
                return View("Lockout");
            case SignInStatus.RequiresVerification:
                return RedirectToAction("SendCode", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl, RememberMe = model.RememberMe });
            case SignInStatus.Failure:
            default:
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid login attempt.");
                return View(model);
        }
    }
```

and here is the snippet of the angular service that is calling the Login method

```js
        var loginUser = function (email, password, returnUrl) {
            var req = {
                method: 'post',
                url: '/Mysite/Login',
                headers: {
                    'Content-Yype': undefined
                },
                data: {
                    model: {
                        Email: email,
                        Password: password,
                        RememberMe: false
                    },
                    returnUrl: returnUrl
                }
            };
            return $http(req)
                .then(function (response) {
                    return response.data;
                }, function (reason) {
                    return reason;
                });
        };
```

the response throws me internal error with status 500.

Does angular.js support asynchronous calls to web methods?

Thanks and appreciate your help

Comment: The action is decorated with [ValidateAntiForgeryToken], are you passing a request verification token with the data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using the [ValidateAntiForgeryToken] decorator, the action needs a request verification token to be passed in the post data.

You could remove [ValidateAntiForgeryToken] but this would leave your action open to tampered requests.

The other option is to add an anti forgery token to the page and then pass its value in the request.

Your razor view will need a form with a token in it (Note: This is just a dummy form to allow the token to be added to the page).

```
@using(Html.BeginForm("Login", "ControllerName", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "verification-form"}) {
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
}
```

In your javascript, you can then pass its value

```js
        var loginUser = function (email, password, returnUrl) {
            var req = {
                method: 'post',
                url: '/Mysite/Login',
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': undefined
                },
                data: {
                    model: {
                        Email: email,
                        Password: password,
                        RememberMe: false
                    },
                    __RequestVerificationToken: $("#verification-form input[name=__RequestVerificationToken]").val(),
                    returnUrl: returnUrl
                }
            };
            return $http(req)
                .then(function (response) {
                    return response.data;
                }, function (reason) {
                    return reason;
                });
        };
```

Comment: Yes [ValidateAntiForgeryToken] was the problem. Thanks. That solved it.

Comment: any chance of marking this as the answer for others then?